# Golang duplicate rails Devise gem password encryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, go, devise, bcrypt, beego

I have to authenticate user in a new app which uses `Beego` framework for `Golang`, twist is that DB is from Rails application where authentication is implemented using `gem Devise` .
I've looked at `gem Bcrypt` implementation
 https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/master/lib/bcrypt/password.rb
But can't  quite grasp how to replicate `encrypted_password` to validate user...
Can you please help me ?

***UPDATE1***
using `bcrypt`  didn't help

> b_password := []byte(password)
>     hashedPassword, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword(b_password, bcrypt.DefaultCost)

I get different passwords.

Comment: What do you exactly want?

Comment: Are you trying to encrypt the password using bcrypt? or you men from a view perspective?

Comment: I want to check is provided email & password valid on golang side. so  I've to encrypt password the same way `devise`  does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out https://github.com/consyse/go-devise-encryptor exactly for doing this task

Answer (score 0):

This devise encryptor doing same thing as bcrypt auth in golang, also i dont see Rails Devise hash and go-devise-encryptor password hash equal.